# Has anyone got 3DMixer in iphone working with "true" spatialization?

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audiounit

I have been fiddling with the 3D Mixer on the iphone but it seems that it is not able to give the effect of HRTF for a surround sound. Im wondering if any of you guys got better luck with this audio unit...